# Using subsections of an array in Twig as if they were the main

Tags: php, twig

If I have an array passed to twig like this

```
$values = [
  'title'=>'Title of Page',
  'subsection_a'=>[
                   'title'=>'Title of Subsection'
                  ],
];
```

What I'd want to do is for a specific section in my template, use 'subsection_a' as the base so when I do `{{ title }}` it says "Title of Subsection" rather than "Title of Page"

I'm very unfamiliar with Twig, and I'm testing it as a replacement for a template engine I threw together for a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dividing the main proportion of your templates in subtemplate you can do it with the keyword `with`:

<kbd>controller.php</kbd>

```
echo $twig->render('main.twig, [
    'title' => 'parent',
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    'bar'   => 'foo',
    'child' => [
        'title' => 'Child',
        'foo'   => 'Foobar',
    ]
]);
```

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<p>{{ foo }}</p>

{% include "child.twig" with child %}
```

<kbd>child.twig</kbd>

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<p>{{ foo }}</p>
```

[twigfiddle](http://ideone.com/JKv0uv)

Comment: That's probably exactly what I need.  I'm curious, can I use that same logic with a straight {% with child %} section or does that only work when used with include?

Comment: Darn, was hoping that was a loophole.  Either way, this does what I need.  I can either change my template variable names, or separate out into a file.  Either way will work.  I marked this as the answer.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Twig-way of achieving this.
If it's just for ease of use, you could set a short variable, such as

`{% set sub = subsection_a %}`

This would allow you to write {{ sub.title }}.

You could create a new array with twig, merge the specific subsection, but in your case, it would make managing the code more difficult, you could have duplicate and it might not be worth the trouble.